# Code to get total number of words and number of lines starting with H

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I am learning File Handling in python. I tried to write a program to display the number of lines starting with 'H' and the total number of words in the file. Even though the text file is not empty, it only printed 0 for both.
What's wrong here?

```
with open("para.txt","a+") as f:
    f.write("As I said: not all things should be left up to god.")
    lines = 0
    # to display the number of lines starting with H
    l = f.readlines()
    for i in l:
        if i[0] == "H":
            lines += 1
    print("No. of lines starting with H is", lines)

    #to display the total number of words in the file
    data = f.read()
    split_data = data.split()
    count = 0
    for i in split_data:
        count += 1
    print("Total number of words:", count)
    print(f.tell())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def f(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
        length_of_lines = len(lines)
        length_of_lines_start_with_h = len([i for i in lines if i[0] == 'H'])

    return [length_of_lines, length_of_lines_start_with_h]


f('b.txt') #supposing a text file in you computer named "b.txt"
# [8, 1] #--> 8 lines, 1 line start with 'H'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("para.txt","r") as f:
text=f.readline()
l_text=text.split(".")


lines=0
words=0
word_list=[]
for i in l_text:
    splited=i.split(" ")
    word_list.append(splited)
    if i[0].lower() =="h":
        lines+=1

for i in word_list:
if i[0].lower() == "h":
    word+=1
```